# WooCommerce - how to display product category above product with full details

Tags: plugins

i'm new in wordpress so please suggest me.
i'm selling ring, earings, chains, ect.
ring, earings "catogry"
and ring-1, ring=2 product.
so i want to show on shop page my catogry and on click catogry my products will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm not totally mistaken you can configure woocommerce that way

-shop
--category1
---product1.1
---product1.2
--category2
---product2.1
---product2.2

without any coding and very easy from your wordpress backend, take a look at:
"woocommerce>settings>catalog"

Answer (score 0):

thanks but i get my answer any other source.
and my answer is

```
$args = array(
//'number'=> $number,
//'orderby'=> $orderby,
//'order'=> $order,
'hide_empty'=> false,
//'include'=> $ids
);
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    foreach($product_categories as $catval)
    {$catval->name;
    $link = esc_url( get_term_link( $catval, $catval->taxonomy ) );
    // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catval->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
```